# Swift Closures Within Extensions

Tags: ios, swift, closures, extension-methods

I'm trying to use closures within extensions in swift but I'm running into a little bit of trouble. I've tried several things like trying to combine stored properties in swift with normal closures but it seems everything I've tried gives me an error. Below is my best code so far. One error I get with this code is "use of unresolved identifier 'self'" but when I refer back to self(the Int) in the square() func, I do not get this error. The other error is "extensions cannot contain stored properties " but I thought they could? Thank you very much for any help is great! I hope this helps future viewers.

```
extension Int {
    var timesX: Int = { (multiplier: Int) -> Int in
            return self * multiplier
    }
    func square() -> Int {
        return self * self
    }
}
```

Comment: `func timesX(multiplier: Int) -> Int { return self * multiplier }`

Comment: did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Int {
    func timeX(times : Int) -> Int {
        return times * self
    }
    func square() -> Int {
        return self * self
    }
}
```

This should be the solution of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You defined the closure expression very well. As closures are reference types, you can assign them to a constant or variable (in your case its a variable timeX). But its Type is wrong here.

See the below code:

```
extension Int {
var timesX = { (multiplier: Int) -> Int in
        return self * multiplier
}
func square() -> Int {
    return self * self
 }
}
```

> var timesX

Example:

```
let number: Int = 10
number.timeX(3) // result 30
number.timeX(5) // result 50
```